# Defining a local gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile

I have moved some of my common fucntionality to a seperate gem and have been using that. In production I include the gem directly from [github](/questions/tagged/github).

```
#common
gem 'engine', path: '../engine'
#gem 'engine', branch: 'master', git: 'source to engine.git'
```

The problem is when I get to development mod I comment out the second line and revert it back before checking in. This is kind of irritating to do every time I've to check in.  I cannot add the [gemfile](/questions/tagged/gemfile) to [gitignore](/questions/tagged/gitignore) as the app is still under development and we keep modifying this file all the time.

I tried grouping them separately using

```
group :development, :test do
   gem 'engine', path: '../engine'
group :production do
   gem 'engine', branch: 'master', git: 'source to engine.git'
```

But it throws an error saying that I cannot define a gem twice. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

The gem is really defined twice in the two groups, since Gemfile parser just see into a group anyway. Try to close the gem for *production* environment under `if` condition:

```
group :development, :test do
   if ENV[ 'RAILS_ENV' ] != 'production'
      gem 'engine', path: '../engine'
   end
end

group :production do
   if ENV[ 'RAILS_ENV' ] == 'production'
      gem 'engine', branch: 'master', git: 'source to engine.git'
   end
end
```